# How to merge two commands in one, to select entities and add property sets in a quantity schedule table?

Tags: autocad, autolisp

I'm trying to combine to autocad commands to one. The commands is used for selecting entities for a schedule table and adding the property sets.

The first command is: ScheduleSelectionAdd
The second command is: AecAddAllPropSets

My code so far:

```
(defun c:upDateSchedule()
    (command "ScheduleSelectionAdd")
    (command "AecAddAllPropSets")
(princ)
)
```

I have also tried this:

```
(defun c:upDateSchedule()
    (command "ScheduleSelectionAdd" "" "AecAddAllPropSets" "")
(princ)
)
```

Every time it only adds my selected entities to the table and not updating my property sets, so here I'm stuck.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acquire the selection first, using `ssget`, and then pass the selection to each command, for example:

```lisp
(defun c:updateschedule ( / sel )
    (if (setq sel (ssget "_:L"))
        (command 
            "_.scheduleselectionadd" sel "" 
            "_.aecaddallpropsets"    sel ""
        )
    )
    (princ)
)
```

Here, the `:L` mode string excludes objects on locked layers.

Note that the above assumes that these commands only have a single prompt for a selection of objects.